# Why do I get an error when I try to fetch a document from MongoDB?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I use Java Spring Framework and MongoDB in my project.

I create a PasswordRecovery object and save it in MongoDB document using the MongoRepository.

When I try to fetch back from MongoDB the stored object I get an error.

Here is the class that I save in MongoDB:

```
@Document("password_recovery_data")
@Data
public class PasswordRecovery {
@Id
private String id;
@Indexed
private String token;
@Email
private String email;
private LocalDateTime created;
private LocalDateTime expired;
private boolean isUsed;
}
```

Here is repository defenition:

```
package com.priceandbuild.operationaldashboardapi.shared.repository;
import com.priceandbuild.operationaldashboardapi.shared.model.PasswordRecovery;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import java.util.Optional;

public interface PasswordRecoveryRepository extends MongoRepository<PasswordRecovery, String> {
    Optional<PasswordRecovery> findPasswordRecoveryByToken(String token);
}
```

Here is how I save the new PasswordRecovery:

```
private final PasswordRecoveryRepository passwordRecoveryRepository;
PasswordRecovery passwordRecovery = new PasswordRecovery() {};
passwordRecovery.setToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
passwordRecovery.setEmail(email);
passwordRecovery.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
passwordRecovery.setExpired(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1));
passwordRecovery.setUsed(false);

passwordRecoveryRepository.save(passwordRecovery);
```

After the save function is executed the password recovery object is saved in MongoDB:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "3456345635g56756h65"
    },
    "token": "dasdasd34235-ded6-4442-234dsfdsf-334terffe4",
    "email": "don@mail.com",
    "created": {
        "$date": "2022-03-13T23:32:19.702Z"
    },
    "expired": {
        "$date": "2022-03-14T23:32:19.885Z"
    },
    "isUsed": false,
    "_class": "com.website.opdash.shared.service.auth.AuthServiceImpl$1"
}
```

I am trying to get the value from the MongoDB document saved like that:

```
Optional<PasswordRecovery> passwordRecoveryOptional =
passwordRecoveryRepository.findPasswordRecoveryByToken(token);
```

But I get an error when I try to fetch saved earlier document:

```
No property this$0 found on entity class com.website.opdash.shared.service.auth.AuthServiceImpl$1 to bind constructor parameter to!
```

It looks like the issue was caused by the value of the property _class saved password recovery document in MongoDB.

I spent a couple of hours on this issue, but I don't understand why exactly I get this error, please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: you need to provide `AuthServiceImpl` class and it's usage

Comment: Your sample code for class `PasswordRecovery` is missing the imports. As such I cannot compile.  I have no idea what import should exist for attribute `@Data` or `@Email`.  As such the main logic cannot call `setEmail()` or others similar.  Please include complete snippets including imports.

Comment: For those following along - add the following dependency...

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
    <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
    <version>1.18.22</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

Answer (score 4):

I think you are totally right and the issue was caused by the value of the property `_class` saved password recovery document in MongoDB: in a nutshell, MongoDB is unable to create a new instance of the class stored in the `_class` field when you try to read it later.

If your question is accurate, my guess is that the following code fragment is defined in the `AuthServiceImpl` class:

```java
PasswordRecovery passwordRecovery = new PasswordRecovery() {};
passwordRecovery.setToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
passwordRecovery.setEmail(email);
passwordRecovery.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
passwordRecovery.setExpired(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1));
passwordRecovery.setUsed(false);

passwordRecoveryRepository.save(passwordRecovery);
```

Please, note the following line, especially the curly braces at the end of the statement:

```java
PasswordRecovery passwordRecovery = new PasswordRecovery() {};
```

When using these curly braces after the `PasswordRecovery` constructor invocation you are creating an instance of an [an anonymous class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html), not just instantiating a new `PasswordRecovery` object.

To make the point clear, please, consider the following test case.

Given:

```java
package com.website.opdash.shared.service.auth;

public class AuthServiceImpl {

  public void setPasswordRecoveryData() {
    PasswordRecovery passwordRecovery = new PasswordRecovery() {};
    System.out.println(passwordRecovery.getClass());
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    AuthServiceImpl impl = new AuthServiceImpl();
    impl.setPasswordRecoveryData();
  }
  
}
```

Then, the `System.println` statement will output:

```
com.website.opdash.shared.service.auth.AuthServiceImpl$1
```

As you can see, this value is the one MongoDB is actually storing when saving your data in the `_class` field.

To solve the problem, just get rid of these curly braces when creating your `PasswordRecovery` object:

```java
// Just instantiate the object
PasswordRecovery passwordRecovery = new PasswordRecovery();
passwordRecovery.setToken(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
passwordRecovery.setEmail(email);
passwordRecovery.setCreated(LocalDateTime.now());
passwordRecovery.setExpired(LocalDateTime.now().plusDays(1));
passwordRecovery.setUsed(false);

passwordRecoveryRepository.save(passwordRecovery);
```

It will allow you to successfully recover the information later.

Comment: Explained perfectly... Good answer. :)

Comment: I was able to prove out this answer.  As stated by @jccampanero - just remove the extra curly braces and your sample code functions as expected.